# how to add new calender in android programatically

Tags: android

I am developing a Bluetooth sync application in which i am syncing all contacts and calender events with outlook express.

I want event syncing in my own calendar, not Google account's calendar but I haven't found any solution on "how to create new calenders in android". please help me if any one have its solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access to Calendar Content Provider.
Your app need to have specific permission to read/write calendar.

Hope, it help you!

Comment: i have used content providers but it give us the facility to read and add calendar events only but i want to enter a new calender say calendar with a name 'Personal_calender'. we don't have this option in android device too that we add new calendar manually. for the first time when we give Gmail account details to the market it automatically inserts a new calendar but it did not give us the permission to do it manually. i want to do it programmatically.

Comment: I'm interested in the creation of a new calendar, do you solve it?